# Does Gaseous Form take non-magic damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

I want to know if it's possible to damage a person who uses *gaseous form* with non-magic weapon.

From rules, which says it has resistance, it is possible and the damage is reduced to half.

On the other hand you cannot hurt something that is basically a cloud.

Or am I just misunderstanding what resistance in D&D means?

Comment: Sure you can hurt something that is a cloud, if you are working the simulationist angle.  You can disperse it with a powerful gust of wind.  If it's water vapor, you can freeze it ... etc.  Some gases are flammable, so being hit with fire may flash ignite the gas ...

Comment: @KorvinStarmast: Yeah, IRL, something that's just a cloud should be trivial to hurt -- just wave a fan at it and watch it disperse.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Yes, *gaseous form* is susceptible to non-magic damage

SRD page 146 has this to say about *gaseous form*:

> The target has resistance to nonmagical damage, and it has advantage on Strength, Dexterity, and Constitution saving throws.

And page 97 of the SRD says, "*[i]f a creature…has resistance to a damage type, damage of that type is halved against it.*"

Therefore, any creature under the effect of *gaseous form* takes half damage from non-magical attacks.

---

> On the other hand you cannot hurt something, that is basically cloud.

This is a dangerous line of thinking. D&D is a game, and thus has rules. The rules specifically say that a gaseous creature still takes some damage from non-magical attacks. The spell says you have resistance to non-magical damage. Therefore, you only have resistance and not immunity.

Comment: "The name and description of the spell are just flavour text to the rules of the spell." There is some debate about this: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/78012/

Comment: A byproduct of all the 4e I played, I guess. But the point stands: the spell grants resistance, not immunity.

Comment: The word vulnerable might not be the best choice, given that it has a mechanical definition in 5e

Comment: This sounds like a case where Rule 0 is prominently in play.