# Does changing the outside dimensions of a Bag of Holding break anything mechanically?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

One of my players made a character who's a 2ft. tall gnome artificer. He just created a bag of holding as his wondrous invention, but the exterior dimensions (2ft. wide by 4ft. deep) is bigger than him. So I decide to make it a drawstring backpack with a 2ft. mouth so he still has the same insertion dimensions, and 1.5ft. deep so he can wear it like a backpack and not trip.

Does this change anything about the bag mechanically? Does this seem like a reasonable change?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The description of the Bag of Holding states (DMG 173-174):

> If the bag is overloaded, pierced, or torn; it ruptures, is destroyed, and its contents are scattered in the Astral Plane [...] Placing a bag of holding inside an extradimensional space created by a Handy Haversack, Portable Hole, or similar item instantly destroys both items and opens a gate to the Astral Plane.

This suggests that the interior of the bag is a confined space/pocket dimension within the Astral Plane, and that the mouth of the bag is in essence a portal to this space. Thus, it should not be affected by the outside dimensions on the Material Plane.

See also: [Related answer to the question "Is the “pocket dimension” a familiar goes into a demiplane or an extradimensional space?"](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/105930/41726)