# Can a cart be placed in the Bag of Holding?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, vehicles

My DM said my party could place our cart in the *bag of holding*, since it only weighs around 200 lbs, whereas the capacity of the bag is 500 lbs and 64 cubic feet. I have my doubts, since the cart just seems too big to fit in the bag's opening. According to the official rules, is it possible to fit a cart in the *bag of holding*?

Comment: Hi Crazor2000, welcome to the site! You may want to take the [tour].

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: Related: [Does changing the outside dimensions of a Bag of Holding break anything mechanically?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/125012/does-changing-the-outside-dimensions-of-a-bag-of-holding-break-anything-mechanic)

Answer (score 7):

From the description of a bag of holding:

> This bag has an interior space considerably larger than its outside dimensions, roughly 2 feet in diameter at the mouth and 4 feet deep

So you're going to have some issues trying to fit a cart through the opening.

Comment: I'd also note that 64 cubic feet is just a 4x4x4ft space (as the space in the bag is 4 feet deep, it follows that it's probably about 4 feet across as well) - even if the diameter of the opening was not an issue, the cart is almost certainly too large for the interior dimensions.

Comment: They also sell axes which will solve the problem. Regardless, rule 0, DM said it fits so it does.

Comment: Portable hole would be a better garage.

Comment: @Carcer No interior shape is listed for the bag, just a volume, so it isn't limited to just 4 feet deep. The opening is still a problem.