# Does the extradimensional space created by Mordenkainen's Magnificent Mansion count as a separate plane?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, planes

[*Mordenkainen's Magnificent Mansion*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/magnificent-mansion)

> You conjure an extradimensional dwelling in range that lasts for the duration

Does this extradimensional space count as a separate plane for effects dependent on the plane a player is on. 
For example, take 
[*Sending*](https://5thsrd.org/spellcasting/spells/sending/).

> [...] if the target is on a different plane than you, there is a 5 percent chance that the message doesn't arrive.

What about the various planar effects outlined in the *Dungeon Master's Guide*?

(*DMG* p. 47)

> Creatures on the Astral Plane don't age or suffer from hunger or thirst

(*DMG* p.61)

> As an action, a creature on Limbo can make an Intelligence check to mentally move an object on the plane that it can see within 30 feet of it.

Comment: Related if not near duplicate of: [Is there a difference between a plane of existence and an extradimensional place?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/138107/is-there-a-difference-between-a-plane-of-existence-and-an-extradimensional-place)

Comment: How is your question different than the one slagmoth links to?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a difference between a plane of existence and an extradimensional place?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/138107/is-there-a-difference-between-a-plane-of-existence-and-an-extradimensional-place)