# Can Plane Shift be used to transport from mordenkainen's magnificent mansion to the same plane the mansion was created?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, planes, teleportation

The text of *Mordenkainen's Magnificent Mansion* (mmm) states:

> You conjure an extradimensional dwelling in range that lasts for the Duration.

*Plane Shift* states:

> You and up to eight willing creatures who link hands in a circle are transported to a different plane of existence.

Can a party *plane shift* from the mansion to the same plane they where in when they created the mansion? i.e. they create the mansion in the material plane, go into the mansion and then *plane shift* to a new location in the material plane?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov agree, that the trick works fundamentally hinges on whether or not the mansion is in fact a separate plane of existence so that question is relevant (and I was going to refer to it in an answer I was drafting before you beat me to it) but the question is about a specific different application of that result.

Comment: At the very least, these are related: "[Does the extradimensional space created by Mordenkainen's Magnificent Mansion count as a separate plane?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/163901)" and "[Is there a difference between a plane of existence and an extradimensional place?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/138107)" and "[Is the “pocket dimension” a familiar goes into a demiplane or an extradimensional space?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/105928)"

Comment: Are you asking if MMM and the Material are different planes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Sure.

*Mordenkainen's Magnificent Mansion* creates what is called a demiplane:

> Demiplanes are small extradimensional spaces with their own unique rules. They are pieces of reality that don’t seem to fit anywhere else. Demiplanes come into being by a variety of means. *Some are created by spells*, such as demiplane, or generated at the desire of a powerful deity or other force. They may exist naturally, as a fold of existing reality that has been pinched off from the rest of the multiverse, or as a baby universe growing in power. A given demiplane can be entered through a single point where it touches another plane. Theoretically, a plane shift spell can also carry travelers to a demiplane, but the proper frequency required for the tuning fork is extremely hard to acquire. The gate spell is more reliable, assuming the caster knows of the demiplane.

So while in the mansion, *you are not on the material plane*. *Plane shift* says:

> You and up to eight willing creatures who link hands in a circle are transported to a different plane of existence. You can specify a target destination in general terms.

Since the *Mansion* is on a different plane of existence from the material plane, you can *plane shift* from the *mansion* to a location on the material plane, assuming you have a tuning fork properly attuned to the material plane.