# Does a PC's bag of holding function inside the gem used as the component of a Minimus Containment Imprisonment spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items

I know nothing can pass through the gemstone using planar travel, but does that count for things that are inside the gemstone and don't "pass through"? If the bag of holding does work would the contents be huge relative to the PC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### This is up to your GM

The entirety of rules text for [Minimus Containment](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Imprisonment#content) is

> **Minimus Containment**: The target shrinks to a height of 1 inch and is imprisoned inside a gemstone or similar object. Light can pass through the gemstone normally (allowing the target to see out and other Creatures to see in), but nothing else can pass through, even by means of teleportation or planar Travel. The gemstone can't be cut or broken while the spell remains in Effect.

The spell does not explicitly state anything about also shrinking the targets equipment, nor is there Sage Advise on it (I guess it is a rare occurence for this to happen to players, it is more of an NPC plot device), but I think this is implicitly the case. Which would man that your Bag of Holding would likewise shrink.

And [Bag of Holding](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/bag-of-holding) states

> This bag has an interior space considerably larger than its outside dimensions, roughly 2 feet in diameter at the mouth and 4 feet deep. The bag can hold up to 500 pounds, not exceeding a volume of 64 cubic feet. The bag weighs 15 pounds, regardless of its contents. Retrieving an item from the bag requires an action.
> If the bag is turned inside out, its contents spill forth, unharmed, but the bag must be put right before it can be used again.

The objects in the bag are in an extradimensional space and there likely in their original size. It will be up to your GM to determine

- if they can enter the interior of the diamond at all or the *bag* just does not function within the prison (by the arguments of the answer given by @ThomasMarkov, that this would constitute planar travel and is forbidden by the gem)
- if they are subjected to being minimized upon entering and usable by you
- if the opening of the now minimus bag is too small to retrieve any of them
- if they remain their original size and are sent to the *Astral Plane* instead of entering the gemstone
- if they remain their original size and are destroyed by being crushed within your minimus indestructible prison, along with your minimus self

Go ahead, try to retrieve something. *Are you feeling lucky, punk?*

Answer (score 4):

#### Entering a bag of holding is planar travel.

The interior of a bag of holding is an extradimensional space, as explored in this Q&A: [Is the interior of a Bag of Holding actually an extradimensional space?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/154698/62294) Goodguy5's [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/154699/62294) is succinct and clear:

> ### Yes, Bags of Holding create extradimensional space
>
> From the description of Portable Hole:
>
> > [snip]...Placing a portable hole inside an extradimensional space created by a bag of holding, Heward's handy haversack, or similar item ...[snip]
>
> (similar wording exists for the Bag of Holding and Heward's Handy Haversack, as well)

Since the interior is an extradimensional space, entering or leaving the bag of holding constitutes "planar travel", which Minimus Containment does not allow

> nothing else can pass through, even by means of teleportation or **planar travel.**

So a creature stuck inside Minimus Containment could neither enter a bag of holding, nor take anything out of it.

Comment: @Thomas_Markov So nothing can pass through the inside of the gem as well? In that case wouldn't the PC be frozen in place as they count as "something"

Comment: @Cellheim I'm not sure what you're asking there, sorry. I'm saying that the inside of a bag of holding *is another plane*, and Minimus Containment does let anything in or out via other planes.

Comment: @Thomas_Markov I thought that the "nothing can pass through the gem" condition of the spell only affected things exterior to the gem as I thought the PC could move around inside the gem and cast dispel magic and stuff. If nothing can pass through the inside of the gem as well, does that not freeze the imprisonee in place?

Comment: @Cellheim It seems clear enough to me that it just means things cannot enter the gem.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I think the point is that the bag is already inside the gem, so it is not "passing through" the gem by means of planar travel, nor would its contents pass through

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin But it is. Leaving the bag of holding into the gem means going from a different plane directly into the gem, which is exactly the definition of entering the gem via planar travel.

Comment: @Cellheim Would it clarify things if we said that the outside of the *bag of holding* was inside the gem, but the inside of the *bag of holding* is on another plane?