# Is an item inside a bag of holding still considered to be in the same plane?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

Multiple features and items have text specifying they only work if the "target" is located on the same plane, so if said target (object or creature) entered a bag of holding, would an ability that specifies "same plane" still work?

Comment: Related: [Is the interior of a Bag of Holding actually an extradimensional space?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/154698/52137)

Answer (score 7):

## No is is not

This has been explicitly answered by the [Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf):

> **Are extradimensional spaces, such as a demiplane or
> the space created by rope trick, considered to be on a
> different plane of existence?** An extradimensional space
> (aka an extraplanar space) is outside other planes. Therefore,
> if you’re on the Material Plane and your foe is in an extradimensional
> space, the two of you aren’t on the same plane of existence.