# While under a spell effect that's suspended, can you still make saving throws?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, saving-throw

Per [this Q&A](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/100038/paladin-aura-of-courage-effects), creatures under the effects of spells or abilities that give them the frightened condition have that condition suspended while in a Paladin's Aura of Courage.

But if the spell/ability that frightened them gives opportunities for saving throws against that condition (e.g. at-end-of-turn, or once-out-of-sight-of-frightening-creature), do they still make those saving throws if the opportunities come up and the condition is suspended?

e.g. An enemy spellcaster casts Cause Fear on me, and I fail the save and am now frightened (but can make saves at the end of each of my turn to remove the effect). My party's Paladin comes within 10 ft of me, giving me immunity to frightened and so the condition is suspended.

Do I:

A) Continue to make saves each turn to remove the effect even while in my Paladin's Aura?

or

B) Not make any saves while the condition is suspended, and if my Paladin moves away from me within the duration of the spell, become frightened again and only then start making saves against it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### You can make the saves

The Aura suspends the frightened condition, rather than the spell causing it. The fact that you can make a save against the spell is part of its effect, separate from its other effect of giving you a condition. Thus you can still make the saves against the spell and would also show up as affected by it when checked with *detect magic*, for example.

Comment: Contrast: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/78680/9552

Comment: @András "suppress any effect causing a target to be charmed or frightened" That explicitly suppresses the effect itself, not the condition.

Comment: @Szega Thanks! Are you saying that Calm Emotions is a distinct case where you would not make the saves?

Comment: @Vigil As there is no general rule, every case is distinct. The relevant description should tell you whether the cause or the effect is suppressed. Or, if you are the DM, you could make a ruling to handle all these consistently one way or the other.