# Can I use a Ring of Telekinesis to tie someone in ropes and then levitate them?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

My character recently obtained a Ring of Telekinesis:

> While wearing this ring, you can cast the Telekinesis spell at will, but you can target only Objects that aren't being worn or carried.

I also happen to have some unbreakable rope. Since the Telekinesis spell allows me to

> ...exert fine control on Objects with your Telekinetic grip, such as manipulating a simple tool, opening a door or a container, stowing or retrieving an item from an open container, or pouring the contents from a vial

Could I use my action to wrap/tie an opponent in rope, and then move the rope into the air, dragging them along?

Comment: Somewhat related: [Can the levitate spell carry a whole party on a platform](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/143925/can-the-levitate-spell-carry-a-whole-party-on-a-platform)

Answer (score 3):

The clear intent of the item is to manipulate objects and to exclude manipulating other creatures. Getting extremely technical about what it means to "wear or carry" an item in an effort to sneak around that limitation seems like cheese to me.

Answer (score 2):

I could see an enemy wrapped in rope "wearing" said rope, thereby not allowing you to continue exerting control over the rope with Telekinesis. This interpretation stands in contrast to [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/120716/what-items-are-considered-worn-or-carried) which basically says "everything on a characters item sheet is worn or carried", and I feel an enemy rope binding you would not end up on your inventory, so to speak.

If this decision was up to me as DM, I would allow it, but YMMV.

EDIT: Addendum: in the case of allowing it, I would, however, grant the ensnared creature a STR saving throw against being moved, similar to the *Immovable Rod*'s DC 30 STR check to move the rod, but probably lower.