# Can you combine an Artificer's Enhanced weapon infusion with a +3 magic weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, class-feature, artificer, artificer-infusions

The Artificer's Enhance Weapon infusion (ERftLW) grants a +1 (+2 at 10th level) bonus to attack and damage rolls made with the infused weapon. Is it possible to combine this infusion with a magic weapon that already has a +3 magical bonus? Thereby granting a +4(+5 at 10th level) bonus to attack and damage rolls.

I believe it is ok, if you first apply the enhanced weapon infusion and then the +3 from the magic weapon. However I don't know if "(any)" weapon applies to the enhanced weapon (that become magic).

Comment: Related: [Can an artificer use Magical Tinkering on a weapon before infusing it (and have it stay)?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/164579)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, per RAW, since the +3 sword is already magical

> Artificer Infusions
> Artificers have invented numerous magical infusions, extraordinary processes **that rapidly create magic items.**  To many, artificers seem like wonderworkers, accomplishing in hours what others need weeks to complete. {bolding mine; E:RftLW)

And there is another rule under *Infusing an Item*:

> "Whenever you finish a long rest, you can touch a non-magical object
> and imbue it with one of your artificer infusions, turning it into a
> magic item." (E:RftLW)

[There aren't any rules *yet* in D&D 5e that modify a magic item](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/63333/22566). The Enhance Weapon feature as a sub set of the Artificer Infusion feature indicates that the infusion itself does {something magical} and ends up with a magical weapon.  Since the +3 weapon is already magical, it isn't eligible for an upgrade.  What your artificer needs to do in order to Enhance a weapon is find one that isn't magical, and then make it magical.

Answer (score 28):

### Infusions can only be applied to mundane items.

If you look at the description of the Artificer's *Infuse Item* feature it specifies that the item must be non-magical (*Eberron: Rising from the Last War*, 57).

> At 2nd level you gain the ability to imbue **mundane items** with certain magical infusions

> Whenever you finish a long rest you can touch a **non-magical object** and imbue it with one of your artificer infusions, turning it into a magic item.

Answer (score 4):

This does not work.

The enhanced weapon infusion says:

> This magic weapon grants a +1 bonus to attack and damage rolls made with it.

The weapon infusion specifies exactly what the weapon becomes: a +1 magic weapon.