# Can I add an Artificers infusion to my pact blade?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, warlock, artificer, artificer-infusions

In the Artificer section that talks about Artificer infusions it says "you gain the ability to imbue mundane items with certain magical infusions". So if I was to use an Artificer infusion on a normal weapon (Greatsword in my case) and then can I use the pact blade ability on that weapon, would it keep the infusion because the weapon does turn magical and the infusion says it can be used **only** on nonmagical items

Comment: This question is different from the other one ("[Does the artificer's Enhanced Weapon stack on top of hexblade's Improved Pact Blade?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/172149)") because Improved Pact Weapon has further requirements that Pact of the Blade alone does not

Comment: @med it is the basic level of Pact of the Blade that contains the "weapon counts as magical" phrase, not the enhanced invocation. That said, I think it would be better to have that question be a duplicate of *this* question.

Comment: @Rykara Yes, but your pact weapon and improved pact weapon can apply to different sets of weapons entirely. There are weapons you summon from *nothing* and there are magic weapon that you make into your pact weapon through a ritual. That said, I'm now unsure which of those this question is asking about

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### A mundane weapon can be Infused and *then* bonded into a pact weapon

The Artificer's Infuse Item feature states:

> At 2nd level, you gain the ability to imbue mundane items with certain magical infusions. The magic items you create with this feature are effectively prototypes of permanent items. [...]

Notably, you can only imbue *mundane* items and they become *magic items*. Meanwhile the [Pact of the Blade](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/warlock#PactBoon-389) feature states:

> [...] You can transform one magic weapon into your pact weapon by performing a special ritual while you hold the weapon. [...]

Note, this *requires* a magic weapon, where Artificer Infusions require a *mundane* weapon.

Thus, you must first have a mundane weapon, turn it into a magical weapon by applying an Infusion and *then* you can make it into your pact weapon. If you have a magical weapon that is *already* your pact weapon, you have no way of Infusing it because it is already magical.

---

#### A non-bonded pact weapon is *not* magical, so it can be infused

Note that if you are just summoning a non-specific pact weapon using the Pact of the Blade feature, this are what the rules states (emphasis mine):

> You can use your action to create a pact weapon in your empty hand. You can choose the form that this melee weapon takes each time you create it (see the Weapons section for weapon options). You are proficient with it while you wield it. This weapon counts as magical **for the purpose of overcoming resistance and immunity to nonmagical attacks and damage.** [...]

This weapon counts as magical *only for the purposes of overcoming resistance and immunity to nonmagical attacks and damage*, [it does not count as magical for any other purpose](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/98323). Thus, if you summoned, say a Longsword, you could then Infuse that Longsword because it is *not* magical.

Note that any Infusion used in this way would be lost once you shunt the pact weapon away, unlike what happens when you make a magical weapon *into* your pact weapon.

Comment: I might be quibbling, but the wording of the pact weapon does not say it is magical *only* for the purposes of overcoming resistance. I think the lack of the word "only" is significant and I'm not convinced the text prevents the weapon from being considered magical in other ways.

Comment: @Rykara That probably warrants its own question then, but I would say that if a feature lets something count as X *under Y circumstance* that it does that *only* under Y circumstance. Otherwise, it could easily have been phrased "counts as magical". I believe we have a question on this somewhere though. Yes, found one at least: "[Are magic weapons and weapons considered magic for the purpose of overcoming resistances different?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/98323)"

Comment: @Medix2 My answer [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/172152/62294) documents some possibly relevant answers and info.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I don't *think* that actually applies at all here because that's unique to the Improved Pact Weapon Eldritch Invocation which is not being asked about

Comment: @Medix2 Like I said, *possibly relevant*. The logic in my answer or one of the linked answers might apply. But I’m at the park, so I’m not gonna check :P