# Can a Phantom Steed that has ended still move?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, movement, duration

My wizard recently picked up the the [*Phantom Steed*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/phantom-steed) spell, and while the spell is extremely useful, we are running into all kinds of questions. The spell conjures a steed with riding horse statistics, except for it being untiring and having a higher speed of 100 feet. It says:

> When the spell ends, the steed gradually fades, giving the rider 1 minute to dismount. The spell ends if you use an action to dismiss it or if the steed takes any damage.

During that one minute, can you still ride the steed and make it move around?

Comment: I’ve closed this as a duplicate since it’s been asked before. Should have been easy to find, it’s in the first few results when you search the spell name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### It is not possible per spell description.

The quoted rules say

> When the spell ends, ...

not "in the last minute of the duration" or something similar. Hence, the fading occurs when the spell ends, which means that the incredible speed is not granted anymore (see [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/201564/63061) for some insights about spells duration).

#### As a DM, one can rule otherwise.

The DM has the final call on everything. They can thus rule that during this minute the speed of 100 is still granted, or that the fading occurs in the last minute of the duration. Obviously, this may require some attention in running the game, for example during a chase.