# What happens when a Scrying target teleports away, or moves through a portal?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, targeting, teleportation, divination

As the title says, I am unsure on the RAW or RAI of what would happen if a target who is being scried upon were to use the Teleport spell, or some other instant travel spell, for intraplanar only travel.

The relevant parts of Scrying:

> You can see and hear a particular creature you choose that is on the same plane of existence as you.

> On a failed save, the spell creates an Invisible sensor within 10 feet of the target.

> The sensor moves with the target, remaining within 10 feet of it for the Duration.

If the target were to travel outside the plane, then they would cease being a valid target for the spell. However, if the target merely travels within the current plane, does the sensor teleport alongside them? Or does the spell simply end? Or some other effect I haven't considered?

And is it different for spells where the target physically moves through a portal, vs just disappearing and reappearing? e.g. Arcane Gate vs Dimension Door.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### If the target remains on the same plane, your *Scrying* spell remains active.

As long as the target is on the same plane of existence, *Scrying* will follow them for the duration. Note that the spell does not give a form of movement or speed for the sensor, so we can conclude that it likely will teleport along with the target, and the since range is "Self" and is only restricted to "must be on the same plane of existence", we don't have to worry about spell ending from them teleporting out of range.

### If the target changes planes, your *Scrying* will be suppressed (but not dispelled).

Per the accepted answer to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/133379/is-a-spell-suppressed-or-removed-when-the-target-temporarily-becomes-invalid), if a target becomes invalid while under the effects of a spell, that spells' effects are suppressed until one of the following conditions are met.

- The target becomes valid again
- The spells duration expires
- The spell is Concentration, and spellcaster chooses (or is forced) to end concentration on the spell.

The spells duration will continue to expire while suppressed, but the spell will have no effect.