# Do creatures charmed by Charm Person/Animal Friendship attack your allies?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, charmed

Does an affected creature still consider your allies as hostile?

*[Animal friendship](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/animal-friendship)* states:

> the beast must succeed on a Wisdom saving throw or be charmed by you for the spell's duration. If you or one of your companions harms the target, the spell ends.

The description of the [Charmed](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Charmed) condition states:

> **Charmed**
>
> - A charmed creature can’t attack the charmer or target the charmer with harmful abilities or magical effects.
> - The charmer has advantage on any ability check to interact socially with the creature.

Answer (score 17):

### The creature does not automatically became loyal

The spell description says the affected creature "can't attack the charmer". This doesn't mean it can't attack the charmer's allies. This doesn't mean it became loyal to the charmer — it might still consider the charmer hostile. **The spell only says it can't attack the charmer, and the charmer has advantage on social interaction checks, nothing more.** Of course, a DM can decide otherwise.

Speaking of social interactions, the DM has the final word — it is the DM who sets the DC, so a player might easily succeed automatically or fail despite of the advantage.

More about the general idea on how spells work in 5e - [What is the source of the "spells do only what they say they do" rules interpretation principle?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/107637/)

Comment: Under what circumstances would the charmed creature attack allies? What would cause them not to? Are there mechanics to adjudicate it?

Comment: @Lexaire depends on the DM. D&D 5th edition empowers the DM in ways that 3rd, 3.5, and 4th did not. While rule zero has always applied, 5th edition chooses not to explicitly codify many things. If your DM says it does, it does.

Answer (score 6):

## Yes, if it did before you cast the spell

As a general rule, spells only do what they say they do and no more, so whether or not the animal considers you or your allies hostile is unaffected by the spell. ([Source](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/857269923134939136))

---

For example, let's us consider a case where you cast this on a wolf so you can get inside its lair where the ancient plot mcguffin is buried. Ignoring the spell, the GM might decide the players can either fight the wolf, or make a persuasion or intimidation check to get past it if they act accordingly.

If you approach the wolf threateningly, and possibly even start a fight before casting the charm spell then yes, the wolf will continue to consider your allies hostile, they just can't attack you and you get advantage on social interaction checks with them. The GM could also rule that you're at a disadvantage on this check now if you've hurt the wolf, so the advantage from the spell would cancel out leaving you at a normal roll.

If you instead approach alone and cautiously, cast the spell at the earliest opportunity and try to calm the wolf (persuasion) or scare it out of the way (intimidation) you'd be at advantage on the roll, and will find it much easier to get past the creature.

Answer (score -2):

In the charmed state the creature you cast the spell on gets convinced your group mean no harm so as long as your allies don't do anything they wouldn't be attacked however if you are casting the spell to collect the creatures eggs then you must do it personally or the creature will attack the gatherer.

Note that spell's full description says:

> This spell lets you convince a beast that you mean it no harm. Choose a beast that you can see within range. It must see and hear you. If the beast’s Intelligence is 4 or higher, the spell fails. Otherwise, the beast must succeed on a Wisdom saving throw or be charmed by you for the spell’s duration. If you or one of your companions harms the target, the spell ends.

As far as the fluff text says the creature is convinced your group doesn't mean harm to it though I could be wrong as in the end it is fluff text.

Comment: Beware of thinking spells contain "fluff"; they don't in D&D 5e. See [Is there “flavor text” in D&D 5e spells?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/78012)

Answer (score -3):

From the description of the [*charm person*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/charm-person) spell:

> The charmed creature regards you as a friendly acquaintance.

If he regards you as a friend in some way from that meaning then hurting your friends contradicts regarding you as a friend.

This is inferred from basic social skills.

Social interactions with friends that was defined online:
https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=friend

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Personally, there are definitely people I'm friends with whose other friends I might not like. (Of course, open combat isn't involved there...) By extension, I don't think charming a creature will automatically and immediately make it decide to stop attacking your allies - but you would have advantage on social checks to convince it to stop hurting them.

Comment: "_This is inferred from basic social skills_", which all animals (or "beasts" for D&D's purposes) will follow? I don't think so... An animal's social skills are vastly different, hence why the logic of this answer completely falls over.