# Would a level 18+ Champion Fighter recover HP outside of combat?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, fighter, healing

At level 18 a fighter with the [Champion](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Fighter#toc_18) archetype gains the Survivor feature, which lets them recover HP at the start of each turn provided they have more than 0 HP:

> **Survivor**
>
> At 18th level, you attain the pinnacle of resilience in battle. At the
>   start of each of your turns, you regain Hit Points equal to 5 + your
>   Constitution modifier if you have no more than half of your Hit Points
>   left.
>
> You don’t gain this benefit if you have 0 Hit Points.

Does this still apply even if they are not currently in combat?

Comment: So if you have just slightly more than half your HP you can heal by poking yourself for 1 damage a couple of times?

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- Imagine it as the same as when a boxer or mma fighter pounds their chest or slaps their own face just before a fight and it'll make more sense?! maybe.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

## According to Jeremy Crawford, yes

Per a [tweet from Jeremy Crawford](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/976946674181394432), lead designer of the game, the answer is yes.

> The benefit of the Survivor feature happens at the start of each of your turns, whether those turns are inside or outside combat. #DnD - @JeremyECrawford

However, whereas historically his tweets were considered to be official rulings according to Wizards of the Coast, [that has since changed](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/140222/55538), and as a result, such rulings are not definitive.

## The rules themselves also strongly suggest yes

According to the [Basic Rules section on Casting a Spell](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#CastingaSpell), specifically under the subsection for Longer Casting Times:

> **Longer Casting Times**
>
> Certain spells (including spells cast as rituals) require more time to cast: minutes or even hours. When you cast a spell with a casting time longer than a single action or reaction, **you must spend your action each turn** casting the spell, and you must maintain your concentration while you do so. If your concentration is broken, the spell fails, but you don't expend a spell slot. If you want to try casting the spell again, you must start over.

If turns only existed in combat, spells of longer casting times would not be feasible. Other rules on spellcasting also allude to the same "on your turn" concept for actions, bonus actions, etc, with regards to time to cast.

As a result, any ruling against the Champion healing out of combat would also apply to spellcasting out of combat. While not definitive, it strongly suggests that turns do exist even out of combat.

## "...resilience in battle"?

It's been suggested that the use of the words "...resilience **in battle**" in the feature description implies that it only works in combat. While true that 5e doesn't have flavor text ([at least in spells](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/78012/is-there-flavor-text-in-dd-5e-spells)), so all wording should be considered, at the same time there are issues with taking this to imply that all such wording must have applicable and literal meaning.

First, "battle" is a broad and vague term that doesn't find real definition in 5e. "Combat" is well defined and described, but "battle" could just as well mean a prolonged conflict between armies. Without a proper definition of what this means, we can't properly narrow down its application.

Second, there are other examples where such summary descriptions are clearly not intended to be taken literally. Otherwise, Rogues could only use [Sneak Attack](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/rogue#SneakAttack-343) on "enemies", only when they attack "subtly", and the enemy must be "distracted" (not to mention that "Sneak Attack" is not literally limited to attacks while sneaking). Likewise, a [Life Domain Cleric's Channel Divinity: Preserve Life](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/cleric#LifeDomain) feature would only heal creatures that are "badly injured", not just moderately injured. If the use of the phrase "in battle" is taken literally to that degree, so too must these.

Lastly, we also have specific counter-examples of what such "only in combat" restrictions look like. Consider that a Rogue's [Cunning Action](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/rogue#CunningAction-345) ability states: "You can take a bonus action on each of your turns **in combat**". Cunning Action specifies turns in combat, whereas Survivor does not. If the intent was only for combat turns, this should have been included here.

Adding to the designer intent affirming that this specific feature is intended to be used in and out of combat, there's a solid case that "in battle" is effectively irrelevant.

Comment: What changed with the tweets of Jeremy Crawford ? Why are they no longer considered official rulings ?

Comment: @Yotus see this answer : https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/140222/55538

Comment: Healing all the time increases your resilience in battle - it just also increases your resilience *outside* of battle at the same time.  Of course, outside of battle you are less likely to take damage - so the effect of the increase is less.

Answer (score -7):

#### There's textual evidence to support NO.

Remember, in 5e there is no "fluff" decorative (and useless) text. Every single word is a game rule. Bold text added by me, below:

> Survivor
>
> At 18th level, you attain the pinnacle of **resilience in battle**. At the start of each of your turns, you regain Hit Points equal to 5 + your Constitution modifier if you have no more than half of your Hit Points left.
>
> You don’t gain this benefit if you have 0 Hit Points.

Therefore, we have three checks to pass before the trait recovers HP:

1. Current HP not **zero** (since there's no negative HP, saying greater than zero or not zero has the same effect).
2. Current HP not greater than half Maximum Hit Points. (Remember, all roundings are down).
3. **In battle at the start of your turn.**

Only if all 3 tests pass the Champion recovers 5+ Con Mod hit points.

Therefore, no. There's no recovery once out of combat (i.e. with no **real** enemies left).

Mr. Crawford knows the game well and can have his opinion but they are not [official unless ratified](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/140222/11402)

Comment: That was my first thought as well when I read the rule. I'd be curios to know what the people say that downvote.

Comment: "In battle" and "at the start of your turn" should be 2 separate checks. Also "in battle" and "in combat" are different things. If it's not an army fighting an army then it's not a battle, just a fight, so being in combat fighting thieves would also not work. Then I understand "resilience" as resistance, not as "regeneration" or "healing". The description and the mechanics simply don't match and trying to make them match produces nonsense. Very unfortunate.

Comment: If the first line was intended to be a restriction it would've said so. As with most other features this line is clearly in intended to state what the feature represents rather than what it does.

Comment: @Mwr247 Rather than debating Mindwin in comments here, I"d recommend supplementing your answer with the counters to this argument.

Comment: @NautArch The only intent was to offer commentary on what I considered to be issues I saw with this approach. Nonetheless, I've taken your suggestion and folded the comments into my answer instead.